# Is my palindrome program correct and in an organized way?

Tags: python

```
def is_palindrome(x):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x = x.lower()
        if x[i::1] == x[::-1]:
            return("%s Is a palindrome" %(x))
        else:
            return("%s Is not a palindrome" %(x))

print(is_palindrome('racecar'))
```

Here is my palindrome program I was just wondering is it right? I checked using the words racecar and madam and it says they are palindrome and I tested nonpalindrome words and it worked. Can someone tell me if it is wrong and then correct me on my mistakes or If its right but there is an easier way can you show me?

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is this correct?" an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466)

Comment: you should look up codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

There is one major mistake there: you use a for loop which is **always** going to return in its first iteration. The `if ... else ...` statement always includes a return, therefore `i` will never reach anything else then 0 and you only check, if `x[0::1] == x[::-1]`. This might be desired behaviour, then however you should remove the for-loop.

Comment: What should I replace it with then? I'm still kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

just  a advise, you don't need to use the `for` loop, as  palindrome property say, reverse of the word is same as word, so you need to apply that way.

so your code be like this (one of all possible cases):

direct implementation

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word==word[::-1]
```

this function will return `True` OR `False` based on if word is palindrome or not

implementation with the `for loop` ( check that first character is equal to last character , second to the second last character and so on)

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    wlen = len(word)
    for index in range(wlen//2):
        if not word[i]==word[wlen-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

implementation

```
words = ['aa', 'racecar', 'hello']    
for word in words:
    if is_palindrome(word):
        print("{} is palindrome".format(word))
    else:
        print("{} is not palindrome".format(word))
```